# Parallize downloads?

Tags: magento-1.9, amazon-web-services, cdn

I am using cloudfront cdn for which I have I created a cname in my hosting server.

cdn.abc.com  pointing to 3uuo34j3232.cloudfront.net

Can I create multiple cnames like above and use one for skin, one for js and one for media to parallize download? If this is not the correct way what is correct?

cdn1.abc.com  pointing to 3uuo34j3232.cloudfront.net

cdn2.abc.com  pointing to 3uuo34j3232.cloudfront.net

cdn3.abc.com  pointing to 3uuo34j3232.cloudfront.net

or

Create a duplicate distribution and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a separate CNAME for each section (media, skin, js), and it will work fine. This will help parallel downloads for a slightly faster download. There should not be any issues with this as long the CDN URL's are sub-domains of your main domain.

The one area it can cause issues is in the admin, but if you set these URLs on the website view, it will limit it to the front-end only.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I didn't understand your last point. can you elaborate please?

Comment: For the scope, change it from default, to the store in question. This will exclude the admin panel from using the CDN URLs.